# Applescript for Illustrator: How can I make multiple items?

Tags: performance, applescript, adobe-illustrator

I'm using Applescript to add a large number of polygons in Adobe Illustrator. The program is quite slow, however. Is it possible to add a list of items all at once?

Current code (works but slow):

```
repeat while X < 2000
  repeat while Y < 2000
    set myPath to make new polygon in layer 1 with properties {center point:{Y, -1*X}}
    set Y to Y + 1
  end repeat
  set X to X + 1
end repeat
```

I'd like to build a list, and create a *single command* to place polygons at every position on the list.

Any ideas?

Comment: That code generates 4 million polygons, no wonder things slow down. Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Yes! That's right. Building a large image composed of very specific polygons. But I could batch them 1000 at a time, etc. I think it would be faster, as the rate-limiting code seems to be interacting with the Illustrator artboard.

Comment: Are they all the same shape? If so, create a number of them within a new group item, then repeatedly duplicate the group. Rinse and repeat. Otherwise try Adobe’s embedded JavaScript; at least that’ll avoid the Apple events overhead.

Comment: Yes, they are all identical but at different positions. That sounds like it would work, but what would the right syntax be? I'm new to AppleScript so not sure how to use the groups / duplicate functionality.

Comment: `repeat with X from 0 to 2000` will be faster than `repeat while X < 2000`

Comment: `make new group item at layer 1` to create a group. Amend your `make new polygon` command to create your shapes in that. Make, say, a 10x10 grid of those shapes in the group, then use `duplicate group_item to layer 1 with properties {position:…}` to copy the group, repositioning at the same time.

Comment: foo, I think this is going to be much faster - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to sacrifice editability, it might be faster if you rasterize every so often to remove all the objects:

```
tell application id "com.adobe.illustrator"
    tell current document
        rasterize source art every page item with options {resolution:150, antialiasing method:art optimized, color model:grayscale rasterization}
    end tell
end tell
```

Add this into your code in such a way that it runs once every 1000 shapes or so (after the inner loop would run it every 2000 times). This is a trade off you have to make here, because your loop will create 4 million objects.

What exactly are you trying to do? Tell us your desired outcome and we might be able to find you a better, faster solution.